# CSS width 100vw only extending to one side

Tags: css

I'm using the following code:

```
#div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100vw !important;
  height: 210px !important;
  background-image: url('imageurl.com');
  background-position: center;
}
```

What I have is an div that I'm trying to get to fit (width-wise) with a grandparent (screen-width). As you can see in the above code, I have attempted to utilize `width: 100vw`, but it only stretches to the right, leaving the left-hand side as-is.

Does anyone have any idea why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `left: 50%;` and `transform: translateX(-50%);` together.

```
#div {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 210px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ycx2f7vc/)**